# How to shorten geom_smooth lines to fit them within the plot's margins?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the next plot:

[image]

```
Plot<- ggplot(df2, aes(x=Activity.X16, y=RMS.V13AP,colour=Formula)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_capped_cart(bottom="both",left="both") +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x=expression(Real~activity~(m.s^{-2})),y=expression(Acoustic~activity~(m.s^{-2}))) + 
  theme(strip.background=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x =element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0),size = 18),
        axis.title.y =element_text(margin = margin(t = 2, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0),size = 18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 15),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=15),
        legend.title = element_text(size=16, face = "bold"),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,0.025,0.050,0.075,0.095)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("VeDBA.X16" = "black", "RMS.X16" = "darkgrey")) +
  cleanup +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se = F) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se = F)

Plot
```

I would like to shorten the geom_smooth lines, since they exceed the limit regarding y-axis points. Does anyone know if it is possible to set geom_smooth lines dimensions?

Comment: This needs a bit more work. since some of your data point's predictions actually go outside the axis. What I meant is this, is the regression line supposed to represent regression over all points or just the points within the axis?

Comment: you can get the coefficients from the fitted line, but if you plot it within the axis, is this a correction representation?

Comment: The lines are representing all points. If you look at the lines, both lines get until the last point. Black line is shorter because, for instance, the last black point is smaller than the last grey point. Do you understand? The projection of the lines goes until the last x-axis value.

Comment: yes i understand that. if you plot a smooth line with x values that run until for example 0.25 such that it does not exceed, I am saying this can be pretty misleading

Comment: It's like the regression is done on only some parts of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the y-axis.

```
Plot + ylim(0, 0.095)
```

---

Try it on the diamonds dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds)
p1 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + 
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F)

p2 <- p1 + ylim(0,20000)

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2)
```

---

[image]